# What compressed file formats does the Files.app support?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, compression, files.app

What compressed file formats does the Files.app support extracting from? I can't seem to find any official documentation to this effect. Any trial-and-error tales?

Comment: I know it supports .zip with deflate, not deflate64.

Comment: According to https://support.apple.com/HT206481, the Files app supports zip files that are not password-protected. The Deflate Wikipedia article states that "Deflate64 (...) is a proprietary variant of Deflate" and that "several free and/or open source projects support Deflate64 (...) while others, such as zlib, do not". macOS (and I guess iOS) use zlib (it's listed on the Apple macOS opensource website: https://opensource.apple.com/release/macos-112.html), which would explain your findings. **So it seems the Files app supports Deflate-encoded zip files that are not password-protected.**